# How do I get escape_javascript and other helpers in my sprockets pre-processed js file (not a view)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb, sprockets

I'm using Rails 3.1 and the sprockets stuff.

I want to use ERB to pre-process a js file that will then be included using javascript_include_tag. It is generated from code, and so I'm pre-processing it with ERB, but I can't get to the helpers like escape_javascript from ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper

Say my file is called dynamic.js.erb, and it contains

```
obj = {
 name: "test",
 tag: "<%= escape_javascript( image_tag( "logo.png" ) )%>"
};
```

How do I stop it from producing the error:

```
throw Error("NoMethodError: undefined method `escape_javascript' for #<#<Class:0x1067da940>:0x116b2be18>
(in /Users/me/site/app/assets/javascripts/dynamic.js.erb)")
```

When I hit my local server and ask for `/assets/dynamic.js`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can include the rails JS helpers into your own class.

```
class Helper
  include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper

  def self.escape_js( text )
    @instance ||= self.new
    return @instance.escape_javascript( text )
  end
end
```

Then use it in your ERB file:

```
obj = {
 name: "test",
 tag: "<%= Helper.escape_js( image_tag( "logo.png" ) ) )%>"
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I put that class at the top of my js.erb file

Answer (score 10):

Call it through [`ActionController::Base.helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html#method-i-helpers) like this:

```
// file.js.erb
var x = "<%= ActionController::Base.helpers.j image_tag('logo.png') %>";
```

Note that [`j`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j) is an alias for [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript), so you can use the long name if you prefer.

Answer (score 8):

You may also either include `JavaScriptHelper` directly into the Sprockets `Context` class (the class that runs your template):

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper } %>
```

Or even define your helper somewhere else and include that in the template (so as to be able and reuse the helper)

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include MyHelper } %>
```